# Downloading json dummie file with $.ajax

Tags: json, node.js, jquery

I'm making the front end of a webpage where some json is needed for now I'm not doing the back so I made a file called it map.json and placed it on my server.

I'm working with node.js as a server so in the public folder I created a new folder named it jason and saved the file there.

Now I'm making an ajax call to this file, but the program isn't finding it, and when I go to public from the google chrome I don't see the json folder.

What do I have to do to be able to see this file and upload it as it was an ajax call to the server?

here is my jquery code, its in a file in public/javascript:

```
  $.ajax('/../json/map.json', {
    cache: false, 
    dataType: "json",           
    success: function(json) { ... code ... }
  });
```

I really don't know how or what file should I modify in noje.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL path used is technically invalid. Following a leading `/` with `..` attempts to reach the parent directory of the domain's root path, which doesn't exist.

Though the browser may simply ignore the `..`, you should still choose one or the other -- either specify the path from root:

```
$.ajax('/json/map.json', {
    // etc.
});
```

Or relative to the URL path of the current page (e.g., `/some/page`):

```
$.ajax('../json/map.json', {
    // etc.
});
```

You've also stated that that the folder is named "*`jason`*" while the request includes `/json/...`. One may simply be a typo, but make sure they match.

And, assuming you're using the `static()` middleware, the URL will need to match the prefix specified (or lack of one):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// $.ajax('/json/map.json', ...);
```

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// $.ajax('/public/json/map.json', ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I corercted the url and added `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` to the app.js but it still isn't working, you're right the folder is json not jason :p so should I add to the app.js something like this: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/json'));`?

Comment: @AnaFranco I'd guess just `__dirname + '/public'`. The path you give to `static()` is the directory it starts from, so a URL of `/json/map.json` would map to `__dirname + '/public/json/map.json'`.